# i am facing a sorting problem in this program help me with this

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

//the problem I am facing with this  is it does not sorts the array correctly
//what it does is it misses first number and and starts from second sorting

```
package exception;
import java.io.*;

public class Program6 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        System.out.println("enter numbers: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int arr []= new int[n];
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.print("enter int:");
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            
        }
        int limit = n-1;
        boolean flag = false;
        int temp;
        for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
            for(int j =0; j<limit-1; j++) {
                if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]) {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if(flag==false) break;
            else flag=false;
            
            System.out.println("sorted array: ");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues in the presented code:

1. Setting `int limit = n - 1` and additionally decreasing the length in the nested loop: `for (int j = 0; j < limit - 1; j++)` - thus, the last element of the array is excluded from sorting.
   Fix: change condition in the nested loop to `j < limit - i`, then for the first iteration the maximal number "bubbles up" to the last element of array at index `n - 1`.
2. "Printing" the contents of the array **inside** the outer loop using the same loop parameter `i` so that after printing `i` becomes `n` and the outer loop is done after just 1 iteration.
   Fix: move printing of the sorted array *outside* the outer loop when sorting is actually done.

Fixed code is:

```java
int limit = n - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    boolean flag = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < limit - i; j++) { // <<-- Replace limit-1 with limit-i
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if(!flag) break;
}

System.out.println("sorted array: ");
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package exception;
import java.io.*;

public class Program6 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        System.out.println("enter numbers: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int arr []= new int[n];
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.print("enter int:");
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            
        }
        int limit = n-1;
        int temp;
        for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
               boolean flag=false;
            for(int j =0; j<limit-i; j++) {         //Replace limit-1 with limit-i
                if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]) {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if(flag==false) break;
           
            
            System.out.println("sorted array: ");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i wrote 4 3 2 1   for sorting it gave me 3214